# port of connected client in sfml

Tags: c++, tcp, sfml

i do not understand how (tcp-)ports work ( in sfml ).

From my understanding a `sf::TcpListener` is a `sf::TcpSocket` that can not really send or receive data except for accepting connections.

Let's assume i have multiple listeners on different ports: think of them like clients for my game (first port) and a config-tool (second port) which i'm writing right now.

I'd like to handle `sf::Packet`s differently depending on which port i received them.

But here is the problem: I don't know how the connect works, but i guess it must assign a different port ( otherwise i would have two clients both running on localhost connected to the same port). so i cannot `switch` on the port anymore.

- Is there any way i can receive information from a client's implementation in `sfml` to which port it was intentionally connecting?
- Is there a algorithm which i can use to determine which port it was (the current port is close to the intentional port or something like this)?
- Do i need to store this in a `struct` like

  `struct wrapped_socket
  {
      uint16_t intentional_port;
      sf::TcpSocket socket;
  };`

  which would reqire to change my current server-codebase ( call to    `wrapped_socket::socket->send()` instead of `socket->send`, or
- Is there a better, straight-forward solution i did not think of?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different `sf::TcpListener` objects. You check for connections on the first listener object, and put those connections in one collection. Then you check for connections on the second listener object, and put those connections in a second collection.

That way the connections are separate, and can therefore be handled accordingly.

Comment: thank you i'll go this way. my first thoughts about storing all sockets in one collection was, that adding another handler on another port would require almost no code-changes besides simply putting another `case`-statement in which i call another handler. but i think multiple collections will totally kick it, i just iterate over all of them and call the appropriate handlers. so again, thank you. -- do you have any words about my assumptions (different ports) being correct?